# Why were only certain forms of animal fighting illegal in 1920s Kelantan?

Tags: law, animals, malaysia

According to C. C. Brown in [the article](https://www.jstor.org/stable/41492197) "Kelantan Bull-Fighting", as of the late 1920s around Kota Bahru:

> Fish-fighting ( *pelaga ikan* )
> and cock-fighting ( *pelaga ayam*) are popular, particularly during
> the padi season when the bull-rings are closed, but unfortunately
> for their votaries these diversions are illegal. Ram-fighting
> ( *pelaga biri-biň* ) is allowed and is much in favour, especially as
> a curtain-raiser to a big bull-fight, while buffalo-fighting
> (*pelaga kerbau* ) is an even bigger attraction than bull-fighting...

I found this detail intriguing, but had no luck digging up any other references that might explain further. Do we know anything about why (or even when?) fish-fighting and cock-fighting were banned while these various forms of fights between mammals were allowed?